# splice static method is not working over array of objects

Tags: javascript

Could please anyone explain me why I´m getting this error when I´m trying to remove the last item of an array.

Here the array.

```
this.customsTypes = [
    {
        "id": "D1",
        "title": "d1",
        "icon": "",
        "hasDeleteIcon": true,
        "deleteIcon": "<img src=\"assets/icons/trash_icon.svg\">"
    },
    {
        "id": "D2",
        "title": "d2",
        "icon": "",
        "hasDeleteIcon": true,
        "deleteIcon": "<img src=\"assets/icons/trash_icon.svg\">"
    },
    {
        "id": "DISTRIBUCIÓN__18/07/2023",
        "title": "Distribución  18/07/2023",
        "icon": "",
        "hasDeleteIcon": true,
        "deleteIcon": "<img src=\"assets/icons/trash_icon.svg\">"
    }
]
```

Here the use of splice:

```
const idIndex = this.customsTypes!.findIndex((e) => e.id === id);
this.customsTypes!.splice(idIndex, 1);
```

Here the error I get on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property '2' of [object Array]
> at Array.splice ()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot delete property '1' of \[object Array\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115544/cannot-delete-property-1-of-object-array)

Comment: Can you post how are you using this code. What is your `id` variable here

Comment: id value is the value of the property id. For example "D2"